# Angular2 dynamic style

Tags: css, angular, sass

What about dynamic styling.

Imagine you're deploying a unique plaftorm for multiple clients. (SAAS platform)

You deploy ONE webapp folder but these webapp must apply a different theme (color) for each client (exemple configuration : loading colors by domain name).

In angular 2, there is scss but the scss is a compiled language -> so you need to compile each time for each client to compile N webapps. It takes time and it's difficult to maintain.

So the only solution i see:
 - compile scss at runtime (via remote server call, fe:jsass, or js) when loading app and inject the generated css file in head section.

but i think it's an anti-pattern with the (s)css file for angular2 components. 
Moreover the generated file will contains components style that will apply on entire page instead even if component is not initialized.

Have you got any framework or other solution ?

Comment: SCSS is only compiled once (When you build your app) into CSS file. Same goes for the Typescript files, compiled and minified into one JS file.

Comment: You should create a custom [RootRenderer](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/RootRenderer-class.html), that will handle compiling sass or use custom css files. To do that, you will need to create a new platform, that's a big task I never did. See how it works [in browser platform](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.4.x/modules/%40angular/platform-browser/src/dom/dom_renderer.ts#L126). And there is  a [speach about custom renderers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iE-wYf4AaiM) at ng-europe

Comment: great i will have a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this creating a Service that return the colors of some structures that you want to change and inject it into the Components

Example inside the component html:

```
<div [style.background-color]="themeService.getNavbarColor()"></div>
```

And do some logic to get the pattern for each user when App starts and insert into the ThemeService.

Full Example:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core'

@Component ({
  selector: 'my-component',
  templateUrl: './my-component.component.html',
})
export class MyComponent {

    constructor( private themeService: ThemeService){}
}

@Injectable()
export class ThemeService {
    backgroundColor: string

    getNavbarBackgroundColor: string() {
        return this.backgroundColor;
    }

    someLogicToGetTheme() {
        //do stuff
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.someLogicToGetTheme()
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes but it's pity to have to specify colors in non styles files.
In the  Google Web Toolkit (GWT) world you can evaluate value in GSS file. Im' surprised that there is no equivalent.

Comment: Indeed it's pity, but I don't know another way to dinamically change the CSS in production on Angular

Comment: I am trying to achieve the same thing, this project has dynamic themes https://github.com/akveo/nebular/ but the sass code is rather complicated @cassiano